# Windows refusing to delete Eclipse folder

Tags: eclipse, installation

I downloaded Eclipse Juno SR2 and tried to install CDT and Android SDK+NDK, but after that when I tried to run it, it showed some error that said Android ADT 22.2 is required (or something similar) and I had to download it through the SDK. However, I had to cancel the update in the middle and I stopped all work on it for the day. But on the next day when I try to delete the Eclipse folder to start over again, it shows me an error that says one of the folders somewhere inside the eclipse folder has a very long name and cannot be accessed, and after this it just refuses to delete the Eclipse folder. Why is eclipse so difficult to install and even more difficult to remove? I have been having too many unexpected problems with Eclipse lately and it's making me feel choosing eclipse to start learning android is a bad idea. As far as I know Android SDK IDE (the one provided by the android developers website) does not have such problems and is more stable.

1. How do I completely remove eclipse from my computer?
2. Why is it so difficult to install and even more difficult to remove?
3. What is the best alternative to eclipse that has as many features and is more stable?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a recursive command line delete

```
del \*.* /S /F /Q
```

If that leaves behind directories, use `rd /S /Q`

Did you install it deep in your user or documents folder?

I personally think Eclipse is the best option, but this question listed some alternatives:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929574/what-are-alternatives-to-eclipse-for-developing-android-applications